# Mips simulation using verilog , lw instruction not working right

Tags: verilog, mips, simulation, system-verilog, mips32

I'm simulating a  32-bit mips using verilog in a single clock cycle , all the instruction are working right in a single cycle , but the lw instruction doesn't read the memory content in the same cycle but instead it read it the next cycle !! 
Here's the Data Memory module code :

```
module dataMemory (address, writeData, MemWrite, MemRead, clock, readData);

input address, writeData, MemWrite, MemRead, clock;
output readData;
wire [31:0] address, writeData;
wire MemWrite, MemRead, clock;
reg  [31:0] DM [0:32767], readData;

initial
begin
DM[2]=10;
end

always @ (posedge clock)
begin

if(MemWrite)
begin
DM[address]=writeData;
end

if(MemRead)
begin
readData=DM[address];
end

end


endmodule
```

here's the instruction memory module code :

```
module instMemory(address, clock, inst);

input address, clock;
output inst;
wire [31:0] address;
wire clock;
reg [31:0] IM [0:32767], inst;

initial
begin
//IM[0]=32'b00000001000010010110000000100000;
//IM[1]=32'b10001100000011010000000000000010;
//IM[2]=32'b00000001100011010111000000100000;
//IM[3]=32'b10101100000011100000000000000010;
IM[0]=32'b10001100000011100000000000000010; //lw t6 0x0002(zero) *** DM[2]=10***
end

always @ (posedge clock)
begin
inst<=IM[address];
end

endmodule
```

here's the test bench :

```
module final_tb();

reg [31:0] PC;
wire clock, writeSig,RegDst,Jump,Branch,MemRead,MemToReg,MemWrite,ALUSrc;
wire [1:0] ALUOp;
wire [3:0] aluCtl_out;
wire [4:0] writeReg;
wire [31:0] inst,readData1,readData2,in_2, result, writeData,out,readData,address ;

always @ (clock)
begin
$monitor("readReg1=%d , readReg2=%d , writeSig=%b , MemRead=%b , MemWrite=%b , readData2=%d , result=%d , readData=%d ,  writeData=%d,  clock=%b",inst[25:21]
,inst[20:16],writeSig,MemRead,MemWrite,readData2,result,readData,writeData,clock);
end

clock clk(.clk(clock));
PC pc(.in(0),.clock(clock),.out(address));
instMemory im(.address(address), .clock(clock), .inst(inst));
regFile rf(.readReg1(inst[25:21]), .readReg2(inst[20:16]), .writeReg(writeReg), .writeData(writeData), .writeSig(writeSig), .clock(clock), 
.readData1(readData1), .readData2(readData2));
ctrlUnit CU(.OPCode(inst[31:26]), .RegDst(RegDst), .Jump(Jump), .Branch(Branch), .MemRead(MemRead), .MemToReg(MemToReg), .ALUOp(ALUOp), 
.MemWrite(MemWrite), .ALUSrc(ALUSrc), .RegWrite(writeSig));
aluCtl AC(.in_func(inst[5:0]), .in_ALUOp(ALUOp), .aluCtl_out(aluCtl_out));
ALU alu(.in_1(readData1), .in_2(in_2), .aluCtl(aluCtl_out), .zeroSig(zeroSig), .sltSig(sltSig), .result(result));
dataMemory dm(.address(result), .writeData(readData2), .MemWrite(MemWrite), .MemRead(MemRead), .clock(clock), .readData(readData));
signExtend SE(.in(inst[15:0]), .out(out));
mux1 mux1(.A(inst[20:16]), .B(inst[15:11]), .sel(RegDst), .out(writeReg));
mux2 mux2(.A(readData2), .B(out), .sel(ALUSrc), .out(in_2));
mux3 mux3(.A(result), .B(readData), .sel(MemToReg), .out(writeData));

endmodule
```

and the output of $monitor is :

## readReg1= x , readReg2= x , writeSig=x , MemRead=x , MemWrite=x , readData2=         x , result=         x , readData=         x ,  writeData=         x,  clock=0

## readReg1= x , readReg2= x , writeSig=x , MemRead=x , MemWrite=x , readData2=         x , result=         x , readData=         x ,  writeData=         x,  clock=1

## readReg1= x , readReg2= x , writeSig=x , MemRead=x , MemWrite=x , readData2=         x , result=         x , readData=         x ,  writeData=         x,  clock=0

## readReg1= 0 , readReg2=14 , writeSig=1 , MemRead=1 , MemWrite=0 , readData2=         x , result=         2 , readData=         x ,  writeData=         x,  clock=1

## readReg1= 0 , readReg2=14 , writeSig=1 , MemRead=1 , MemWrite=0 , readData2=         x , result=         2 , readData=         x ,  writeData=         x,  clock=0

## readReg1= x , readReg2= x , writeSig=1 , MemRead=1 , MemWrite=0 , readData2=         x , result=         x , readData=        10 ,  writeData=        10,  clock=1

## readReg1= x , readReg2= x , writeSig=1 , MemRead=1 , MemWrite=0 , readData2=         x , result=         x , readData=        10 ,  writeData=        10,  clock=0

here's the wave view : 
[Wave View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lV4M.jpg)

Comment: I tired it but , same problem

Comment: Nonblocking assignments won't make a difference.

Comment: A possible solution is to add a `wait` state, where everything stops, waiting for the module to do his job, and then, in the next clock, you bring everything back to work. Memory operations usually take more than 1 cycle to be performed.

Comment: So what's the problem in my code ??? Sw inst are working well and the others.

Comment: Probably `sw` doesn't care about the other modules. When you run `sw`, it will probably take more than 1 cycle to run, but as you are just saving, the other modules don't care about it. When you LOAD, it's a different story, because you NEED to wait for the memory to end its job and give the result to a register. This isn't expected in `sw` and that's why it's not a problem, while the memory is taking its cycles to save, the other modules keep on working anyway.

Comment: Okay , so where  should i add the wait statement ?

Comment: Between the state where you set your memory to read and the state where you set your register to store the output of the memory. Just for guarantee, you can wait a lot of cycles and check if the memory output is what it should be.

Comment: But the problem is that the mips instructions should be executed in a single clock cycle , so the register must have the value from the memory before the next clock cycle .

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, [Booth's binary multiplication algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm) can take more than 30 cycles to finish.

Comment: Well thank you for helping me , but i solved it by replacing the if statement for MemRead by an assign statement outside the always block , like that :
assign readData = (MemRead==1) ? DM[address]:0; 
and also i changed readData form reg to wire.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by replacing the if statement for MemRead by an assign statement outside the always block , like that : assign readData = (MemRead==1) ? DM[address]:0; and also i changed readData form reg to wire

dataMemory module become :

```
module dataMemory (address, writeData, MemWrite, MemRead, clock, readData);

input address, writeData, MemWrite, MemRead, clock;
output readData;
wire [31:0] address, writeData,readData;
wire MemWrite, MemRead, clock;
reg  [31:0] DM [0:32767];


initial
begin
DM[2]=10;
end

always @ (posedge clock)
begin

if(MemWrite)
begin
DM[address]<=writeData;
end



end
assign readData = (MemRead==1) ? DM[address]:0;


endmodule
```